# Object literal's property 'children' implicitly has an 'any[]' type

Tags: arrays, typescript

How can I set the `myOtherKey` property to have `any`?

Typescript error ..

```
Object literal's property 'children' implicitly has an 'any[]' type
```

Object initialization ..

```
let myObject = {
  myKey: 'someValue',
  myOtherKey: []
};
```

Comment: You could allow implicit any or cast the array to its expected type or instantiate it with `new Array<T>()`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What you could do is just assert yourself what the expected type of that array should be in order to overwrite the compiler's resolution of the **any** type.

```js
let myObject = {
  myKey: 'someValue',
  myOtherKey: [] as string[]
};
```

Comment: This is actually better than my approach. +1

Answer (score 13):

You can also tell Typescript that you don't care about implicit any by setting:

```
 "noImplicitAny": false,
```

in your tsconfig.json.

If you don't want to set it off for the whole project, you can also add this line before 'myOtherKey' line:

```
// @ts-ignore
```

Usually toskv answer is the way to go, but sometimes it's just an overhead to explain everything to typescript (like when you're mocking some object and you want empty arrays saved on some properties).

Answer (score 6):

You would declare the object as `any` e.g

```
let myObject:any = {
  myKey: 'someValue',
  myOtherKey: []
};
```

Comment: I do not think you want `myObject` itself to be any. You'll lose typesafety for the whole object even if you just want one property to be any

Comment: @danielspaniol If you want to keep it type safe then you need to define it as a class.